# Parse Push notifications on Android

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification, android-notifications

I am making an app that will use the Parse.com Push notifications, however it is not working like the guide shows.

The issue is, i have set up the Parse push activity fine, registered the new installation, and am able to see which channels a user is subscribed to. I am able to receive the Push notification from parse, but unable to send from my app.

There are no errors following in logcat, and parse records that a push was sent, but shows that there are "no subscribers" to the channel.

In my onCreate:

```
Parse.initialize(MainActivity.this, "***", "***");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    PushService.subscribe(this, "Everyone", MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

The Push code:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setChannel("Everyone");        
    push.setMessage("Hey!");
    push.sendInBackground();
```

The manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 

<application>
   ....

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

There are no errors in logcat, everything seems to be sent smoothly, but in parse i get the following messages:

My Push

```
You sent this push notification to 0 recipients.

Targeting : channels includes "Everyone"
Sending date : November 28th, 2013 at 9:40 AM
Expiration : None
Full target : { "channels": { "$in": [ "Everyone" ] } }
Full data : {"alert"=>"Hey!"}
```

The only changes i can see from the push that i send vs the Push that parse.com sends is the "Full data" field

Parse Push

```
Targeting : channels includes "Everyone"
deviceType is "android"
Sending date : November 28th, 2013 at 9:21 AM
Expiration : None
Full target : { "channels": { "$in": [ "Everyone" ] }, "deviceType": "android" }
**Full data : { "alert": "hi" }**
```

Thanks in advance for any help / ideas

Comment: Is it really necessary to subscribe to a channel? My push notifications work without doing this step.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should turn on push notification from parse setting on the website parse.com

App -> Settings -> Push Notifications -> Client push enabled (should be on)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I defined a `packageName` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` different of the `build.gradle`... it took 3 hours to realize the error. Maybe it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just You uninstall your application from emulator and you verify that the name of your package in gradle [image]

[image]

make shore that the applicationId "Your Package" is the same  in Android manifest [image]